# Check if it is possible to break a string into chunks?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have this code who chunks a string existing inside a NSString into a NSMutableArray:

```
NSString *string = @"one/two/tree";

NSMutableArray *parts = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"%@-%@-%@",parts[0],parts[1],parts[2]);
```

This command works perfectly but if the NSString is not obeying this pattern (not have the symbol '/' within the string), the app will crash.

How can I check if it is possible to break the NSString, preventing the app does not crash?

Comment: check whether parts is nil or having count as zero if that is than array is not created or at least it has no data separated by "/".

Comment: I don't think this crashes if there isn't an instance of the string. It just returns the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check `parts.count` if you don't have `/` in your string (or only one), you won't get three elements.

```
NSString *string = @"one/two/tree";

NSMutableArray *parts = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] mutableCopy];

if(parts.count >= 3) {
    NSLog(@"%@-%@-%@",parts[0],parts[1],parts[2]);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Not found");
}
```

From the docs:

> If list has no separators—for example, "Karin"—the array contains the string itself, in this case { @"Karin" }.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using the "opposite" function to put it back together...

```
NSString *string = @"one/two/three";

NSArray *parts = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

NSString *newString = [parts componentsJoinedByString:@"-"];

// newString = @"one-two-three"
```

This will take the original string. Split it apart and then put it back together no matter how many parts there are.